# embed.container (ArcGIS Online) iframe using Shiny / R

Tags: html, r, iframe, shiny, arcgis

I'm trying to embed an iframe container, containing an ArcGIS Online map, into a Shiny app.  When run **locally**, the url in the following `server.r` file works as expected, however, I get an empty box when I deploy it to the web by running `deployApp("appName")`:

ui.r:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            type="tabs",
            tabPanel("Arc",
                     br(),
                     htmlOutput("arcFrame")
                     )
        )
    )
)
)
```

server.r:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {

    output$arcFrame <- renderUI({
        map <- tags$iframe(src="http://arcg.is/2jwKdHm",
                           height=600,
                           width=500)
        print(map)
    })
}
)
```

ArcGIS provides the following html for embedding this map in a website:

```
<style>.embed-container {position: relative; padding-bottom: 80%; height: 0; max-width: 100%;} .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container iframe{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;} small{position: absolute; z-index: 40; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: -15px;}</style><div class="embed-container"><iframe width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="provPrepTest" src="//charlotte.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=19da1da27f8a4a6ea508bdd9b10e44a4&amp;extent=-80.7557,35.1872,-80.6,35.3118&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light"></iframe></div>
```

If I swap `src="http://arcg.is/2jwKdHm"` in the above server.r file for `src="//charlotte.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=19da1da27f8a4a6ea508bdd9b10e44a4&amp;extent=-80.7825,35.1246,-80.5669,35.3738&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light"`, then I get a base map, the loads and locally and does deploy to the web.  However, it is without the container features (e.g., tools, the ability to toggle layers, address search).

I have had no luck converting the ArcGIS html above into tags that can be properly render the container with tools, etc., by Shiny.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why `src="//charlotte[etc]` instead of `src="http://charlotte[etc]`?

Comment: That is from the embed text above, starting with `<style>.embed-`.  I.e., the specific text given for embedding the map elsewhere includes that src without the http.

Comment: Have you tried it with `http` and gotten the same result?

Comment: Yes, it does the exact same thing.  It loads the base map, but without also passing the `<style>.embed-container {position.....` and `<div class="embed-container">` arguments, the container and tools do not load as they do with `src="http://arcg.is/2jwKdHm"`.  (Again, the latter only works locally, does not deploy).

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution. In the above example, the embed code did not actually have the `legendlayers=true&amp;` statement that was needed to make layers toggleable.  That change, with the two files below, properly launches the ArcGIS Online map into a web deployed shiny app.

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {

output$arcFrame <- renderUI({
    HTML('
    <style>
      .embed-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 80%;
        height: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <iframe
        width="500"
        height="400"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        title="provPrepTest"
        src="//charlotte.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=19da1da27f8a4a6ea508bdd9b10e44a4&amp;extent=-80.7557,35.1872,-80.6,35.3118&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;legendlayers=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light">
    </iframe>
')
})
})
```

And

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            type="tabs",
            tabPanel("Arc",
                     br(),
                     htmlOutput("arcFrame")
                     )
        )
    )
)
)
```